# Result type of a function creating new document - mongoose schema and model

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In our typescript project there is a `myDocument.model.ts` with a content:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  url: String,
  date: Date,
});

export default mongoose.model("Document", DocumentSchema);
```

In the `repository.ts` there is a function:

```
import Document from "./myDocument.model";
    
function addDocument(url:string):Document {
 let newDoc = new Document();
 newDoc.url = url;
 newDoc.date = new Date();
 newDoc.save();
 return newDoc;
}
```

I want to specify the return type of this `addDocument(..)` function - but cannot. I interpret the export above as `Document` is a `type` like a class, which can be instantiated - and the `newDoc` instance has at least the two fields (url, date), several additional fields like `_id` and `id`, some instance and static methods like `save()` generated by the mongoose.model(...) call. So the function return type should be `Document`:

```
public addDocument(url:string): Document {
  ...
  return newDoc;
}
```

But in this case the TS compiler says

> error TS2740: Type 'Document<unknown, {}, { url?: string; date?: Date; }> & { url?: string; date?: Date; } & { _id: ObjectId; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Document': URL, alinkColor, all, anchors, and 250 more.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making 2 mistakes, namely -

1. When you're adding a signature of return type of function with `Document`, you're unintentionally and mistakenly referring to the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), from DOM, in a browser. Try and hover over the Document, you'll see the description.
2. If you're looking to type it with an instance of the `Document` model, you'll need to use the [`IntanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) utility, with a parameter of `typeof Document`.

```ts
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url: String,
    date: Date,
});

const Document = mongoose.model("Document", DocumentSchema);

// Wrong, here you're using the DOM interface called Document
function addDocumentWrong(url: string): Document { 
    let newDoc = new Document();
    newDoc.url = url;
    newDoc.date = new Date();
    newDoc.save();
    return newDoc;
}

// Correct, here the an instance type of `typeof Document` model as the return type.
function addDocument(url: string): InstanceType<typeof Document> { // Correct
    let newDoc = new Document();
    newDoc.url = url;
    newDoc.date = new Date();
    newDoc.save();
    return newDoc;
}
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqykRm)